# updating access db using vb.net

Tags: database, vb.net

```
Private con As OleDbConnection
Private adapt As OleDbDataAdapter
Private cmd As OleDbCommand

Private Sub RegisterButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RegisterButton.Click
    Dim myqry As String
    con = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\Users.accdb")
    con.Open()
    myqry = "UPDATE RegisteredUsers SET UserName=?, Password=?, RetypePassword=? WHERE Organisation=?"
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(myqry, con)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", UserNameTextBox.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", PasswordTextBox.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", RePassTextBox.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", OrganizationTextBox.Text)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
    MsgBox("Thank You!!")
    Login_Form.Show()



End Sub
```

I can see the msg box and also open the Login Form successfully, however the values inputted are not added/updated in access file providing the connection.

Comment: How do you know they are not added?  `Dim rows= cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` if it is non zero, the row was updated.  You are still burning one connection per query.  `con` should be local to that procedure and `.Dispose` of it when done.  Never ever save passwords as plain text

Comment: And look at `[Password]`.

Comment: Yes, password is (still) a reserved word and needs to be escaped.  How will the system ever possibly use the `RetypePassword` value??? That ought to be compared to what they entered and the Register button remains disabled until they match

Comment: Helpful tip: respond to comments.  If `row` is zero but you cant see the rows in the DB, we could tell you what to do.  As is, the code should be crashing with an error message telling you something.